# How to show the child nodes of drupal menu

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In my admin, I have enabled the Show As Expanded tick, but the submenus do not show.

Here is my code in template.php:

```
$trail = menu_get_active_trail();
$leaf = $trail[1];

if(!empty($leaf['has_children'])) {

    $parameters = array(
        'active_trail' => array($leaf['plid']),
        'only_active_trail' => FALSE,
        'min_depth' => $leaf['depth'] + 1,
        'max_depth' => $leaf['depth'] + 2,
        'conditions' => array('plid' => $leaf['mlid']),
    );

    $children = menu_build_tree($leaf['menu_name'], $parameters);
    $vars['submenu'] = menu_tree_output($children); 
}
```

EDIT:

The right code is:

```
$trail = menu_get_active_trail();
$leaf = $trail[1];

if(!empty($leaf['has_children'])) {

    $parameters = array(
        'active_trail' => array($leaf['plid']),
        'min_depth' => $leaf['depth'] + 1,
        'max_depth' => $leaf['depth'] + 3,
        'conditions' => array('p1' => $leaf['mlid']),
    );

    $children = menu_build_tree($leaf['menu_name'], $parameters);

    $vars['submenu'] = menu_tree_output($children); 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this - might help: https://www.drupal.org/node/685664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'conditions' => array('plid' => $leaf['mlid']),` may be the problem. You should use `p1`, `p2`, ... to filter the parent

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are right -- the right 'conditions' is supposed to be 'conditions' => array('p1' => $leaf['mlid']),